Terminology for two graphs with the same degree sequence
Is there any term for two graphs with the same degree sequence?
For example these two graphs:


Yes. A collection of graphs which share degree sequence are typically referred toward as Degree-Equivalent Graphs (or Isodegree Graphs).
